# load profile onclick search

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been creating an ajax search. I have been wondering how to load the user's profile when clicked on the search results using ajax. I tried assigning the ID of user from database to div using the following code so that I can have an ajax to load the profile:-

```
echo "<div id='$id'><img src='$img' /></div>
```

I wanted to set an **ajax** to **load profile page** and from the profile page, there will be a query to search database for the user. **The variable** ($img/$id) **seems to work on the** `img tag` **but did not work on** `div id`. So, I am stuck wondering how facebook and google+. I tried googling but, no such results were found.

To put it in simpler words, I don't know how to assign a variable (to id or any other place an ajax can get the value from) so that **ajax can load it and then post it to the profile.php so that profile.php can query the database and show the results**.
edit: Since some of you might misunderstand, I don't have a problem with assigning the image, I have problem assigning an **id as a variable** so that I can auto assign it using database .

Comment: What is the workflow? Does a user have to click somewhere on that DIV or should the profile load occur automatically upon page load? What does it mean when you say that the variable "doesn't work"? What is "doesn't work"? You see an empty value for element's `id` property?

Comment: Yes, I see and empty value for element ID property when I use view page source option on browser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load something based on a value, you can try it with the data-* attributes in html. For example:
`<div class="user-link" data-userid="<?= $user_id; ?>"><img src="..." /></div>`
can be retrieved as:

```
$('.user-link').click(function() { 
  console.log($(this).data('userid'));
});
```

edit: http://api.jquery.com/data/

In your case, you could the post in the on-click.

edit 2: I have made the userid a php variable as requested by a deleted comment.

Comment: sir, I have used it with `echo` and I made a variable id using database queries but when I click view page source on browser, I see something like this (empty id):-> `<div id='`

Comment: Plus, I am using `php` so, I don't use divs without the `echo` statemant.. thank you for you help though

Comment: I suggest you read up a bit on how php/html/jquery works. You have a php variable, you put that in the data-userid attribute. My code will not work because A) It contains no jquery post and B) I have no idea what php variable holds the id.